# Xcode 7 Beta permanently stuck on building

Tags: ios, xcode

Everything worked fine until suddenly iPhone apps stopped compiling. I tried to make a few clean sample code apps and nothing works (doesn't matter if it's SpriteKit or UIKit, Objective-C or Swift - I tried them all). I made two screenshots to show you what it looks like:

[image]
*(sometimes like this)*

[image]
*(sometimes like this)*

Does anyone know how to fix it, or do I need to reinstall Xcode?

Comment: what beta build are you on?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include it. Version 7.0 beta 4 (7A165t)

Comment: Did you update to a new El Capitan version recently?

Comment: @Mitley Yes, but I have compiled some apps successfully since the update.

Comment: @Fiodor Happened to me as well, just update to the newest Xcode version.